# MYSQL query with ROW_NUMBER and RIGHT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, row-number

I need to fetch the data according to row number , for eg : If I pass `ROW_NUM=2`, it should fetch me the second row data alone. Can someone please help me with a MYSQL query for this. I tried with `ROW_NUMBER()`, but its not working

```sql
Select arh.ROUTE_NUM,ard.ACTIVE_ROUTE_DETAILS_ID,ROUTE_NUM
from HEADER as arh right join DETAILS ard on HEADER_ID =
ard.HEADER_ID where arh.INFOPRO_DIV IN (050) and  arh.ROUTE_DATE = '2020-11-25'
```

[image]

Comment: What does "but it's not working" mean? Did you get an error? Which? What is your MySQL version? Right outer joins are hard to read. Does that even work with the `WHERE` clause? In an outer joined row `arh.INFOPRO_DIV` and `arh.ROUTE_DATE` are null, so I'd expect the outer joined rows to get dismissed.

Answer (score 2):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  So, to define the second row, you need an `ORDER BY`.  The canonical way to do this in MySQL uses `LIMIT`/`OFFSET`:

```
select arh.ROUTE_NUM, ard.ACTIVE_ROUTE_DETAILS_ID, ROUTE_NUM
from HEADER arh join
     DETAILS ard
     on HEADER_ID = ard.HEADER_ID
where arh.INFOPRO_DIV IN (050) and
      arh.ROUTE_DATE = '2020-11-25'
order by arh.ROUTE_NUM, ard.ACTIVE_ROUTE_DETAILS_ID
limit 1 offset 1;   -- "offset 1" corresponds to the second row
```

Note:  Most folks prefer `LEFT JOIN` to `RIGHT JOIN`.  That said, the `WHERE` clause turns the outer join into an inner join anyway, so I think a regular join would work.  Plus, it makes sense that a join from headers to details would just work.